# Is it okay to use the company hardware for a personal certification exam related to work?

Tags: software-industry, ethics, unprofessional-behavior, india, company-policy

I have a big Microsoft certification exam tomorrow, will it be okay to use my employer's laptop for the exam? It's a professional certification exam not related to the employer's Microsoft ID in any way, although I have completed the learning module on their hardware with my personal ID, I'm not sure if I should go ahead with the exam on their hardware since the examiner would have access to the laptop's camera and microphone.

The exam is related to the technology that I'm working on in the company. This learning helped me with my work, increased my efficiency, and made me better at the work. If I take the exam on their hardware and pass it, will that affiliate employer with the certification in any way? Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is entirely dependent on your company’s policies.  In most places it would be fine, in some it would not.  Is there a reason you are not asking your actual manager this?

Comment: Ask your company.  If you are paying for it, you probably should use your computer to take the exam, if your company is paying for it then they have already set the expectation to use their hardware. Be sure you understand if you should be “on the clock” or not when you take the exam.  Don’t cross the WFH line mixing your personal growth with professional growth by being on the clock while performing an exam your paying for and studying while off the clock.

Comment: From Microsoft's point of view it won't affiliate it with your company in any way, no. Are you asking that or something more akin to companies having 'ownership' of things you create on company time/hardware? Does your boss/company know you are working on this cert?

Comment: @seventyeightist Yes, that's exactly what I'm asking. I use company hardware to answer some questions on Stackoverflow or to learn some coding from Youtube or MS learn. Is that okay?

Comment: @user8078111 - Depends on companies computer policy.  If you have any questions about that policy you should ask your network administrator.   Getting a Microsoft certificate and answering Stack Exchange questions are two vastly different things.  Only one of those is a productive use of your time at work.

Comment: @Donald Thanks for your advice. May I ask which one is productive answering questions or getting a certificate?

Answer (score 2):

> If I take the exam on their hardware and pass it, will that affiliate employer with the certification in any way? Thanks in advance.

No, because you're using your login ID.

But, it might be in your businesses best interests to sponsor this/cover some of the cost. If they're a Microsoft Gold Partner, they will need to have a number of employees who have specific certificates to maintain that level of license. Gold partnership status comes with many perks, such as product licenses.

Comment: It's already free of cost due to the Microsoft Ignite challenge. And I don't think my employer will sponsor any certifications, because my manager once told me to use multiple Credit cards in order to learn Azure freely without any cost. I don't think they are MS Gold Partner although a major chunk is busy maintaining and developing the software and services on Azure cloud., which is quite strange.

Comment: @user8078111 You know that credit card thing is a major red flag, questionably legal, and you really ought to find a different place to work, right?